# HOW I CAN READ EXCEL CONTENT FROM SHAREPOINT USING NODEJS?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

`https://myshare.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/software/Mks12aSccSS-bsaSJdBFBc1dkns?e=QeL6At`

This is URL I copied from browser (It's just example). How I can use NodeJS to read content from it ??

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use npm node-sp-auth (npmjs.com/package/node-sp-auth) to authorize Sharepoint and then use npm sp-download ( npmjs.com/package/sp-download) to download the xls file to a local ( temporary) location.

Then you use npm 'xlsx' ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to read xlsx file contents. It gives access to the workbook, sheets and sheet content as JSON

```
const workbook = XLSX.readFile( 'tmpfile.xlsx');
const sheets = workbook.sheetNames;
// get content for first sheet
const sheetContent = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheets[0]]);
```

Comment: I don't see any instruction about read or pull excel from sharepoint man. It just read content from local file

Comment: you can use npm node-sp-auth (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sp-auth)  to authorize Sharepoint and then use npm sp-download ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-download) to download the xls file to a local ( temporary) location

Comment: Updated answer with details, can you please accept it?